# cakephp WebTechNick paypal plugin(missing controller)

Tags: cakephp

I have downloaded [WebTechNick's PayPal](https://github.com/webtechnick/CakePHP-Paypal-IPN-Plugin) plugin and copied the files 
into /app/plugins/paypal_ipn (exactly as per the instructions). I have 
amended /app/config/routes.php to include the routes for the plugin 
(these are copied straight from the installation instructions). 
 When I access http//:[mysite]/paypal_ipn I am getting a 
missing controller error:

Error: PaypalIpnController could not be found. 
Error: Create the class PaypalIpnController below in file: app/ 
controllers/paypal_ipn_controller.php

I'm baffled as I have followed conventions yet this isn't working. I 
have other plugins working as expected.

What am I doing wrong?

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i would not use this route (besides, its optional)

`Router::connect('/paypal_ipn/:action/*', array('admin' => 'true', 'plugin' => 'paypal_ipn', 'controller' => 'instant_payment_notifications', 'action' => 'index'));`

I want my admin stuff to be in /admin/... not having one rouge plugin doing something else

after removing that you should have the following available

```
site.com/admin/paypal_ipn/paypal_items (shows index like always)
site.com/admin/paypal_ipn/paypal_items/index
site.com/admin/paypal_ipn/paypal_items/view/$id
site.com/admin/paypal_ipn/paypal_items/add
site.com/admin/paypal_ipn/paypal_items/edit/$id
site.com/admin/paypal_ipn/paypal_items/delete/$id

and

site.com/paypal_ipn/instant_payment_notifications/process (need to post to this one)

and

site.com/admin/paypal_ipn/instant_payment_notifications (shows index like always)
site.com/admin/paypal_ipn/instant_payment_notifications/index
site.com/admin/paypal_ipn/instant_payment_notifications/view/$id
site.com/admin/paypal_ipn/instant_payment_notifications/add
site.com/admin/paypal_ipn/instant_payment_notifications/edit/$id
site.com/admin/paypal_ipn/instant_payment_notifications/delete/$id
```

Comment: @dogmatic69 thanks for reply. But I'm getting error message when I trying to access `localhost/myproject/admin/paypal_ipn/paypal_items/index`. Error message is  `You are not authorized to access that location.` I login with admin username and password.

Comment: @dogmatic69 When I try to access this url `site.com/admin/paypal_ipn/paypal_items`. I get following error message. `<?php
class PaypalItemsController extends AppController {

 var $name = 'PaypalItems';
}
?>`

Comment: @dogmatic69 Should I have to add component in app_controller?. I added compoment in `app_controller > PaypalIpn.Paypal'`. After adding this compoment. I get error message controller missing.`<?php class PaypalItemsController extends AppController { var $name = 'PaypalItems'; } ?>`

Comment: there is no component. have you got admin routing setup and what is in your routes file?

Answer (score 0):

This is really old, but the selected answer didn't help solve my problem and this thread is the only one that I was able to find.

The issue is that by default, cakephp (as of 2.5.4) does not enable admin prefixing.  If (like me) you're not familiar with routing or prefixing, I suggest reading the below links:

Routing: http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/development/routing.html

Prefixing: http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/development/routing.html#prefix-routing

But, the quick fix to this (assuming your fine with this plugins admin routing process) is to uncomment the admin prefixing line in your core.php.  DO NOT TRY ADDING THIS TO routes.php.  It won't work.  Rather look around line 152 in /app/Config/core.php and change

```
//Configure::write('Routing.prefixes', array('admin'));
```

to

```
Configure::write('Routing.prefixes', array('admin'));
```

Answer (score -1):

I assume you have added

`var $components = array('PluginName.Example');` (adjust the values)

to your `(app_)controller`?

Comment: I have not added anything in `app_controller`

Comment: there are no components in the plugin so what is he supposed to be adding?